How long could a free African American man be in a slave holding state before being sold
In the Adventures of Huckleberry Finn it is asserted that a free African American man in, I suppose, the state of Missouri (this was related by Huck Finn's father, not the most trustworthy narrator) could be taken and sold as a slave after 6 months in the state. As the book takes place in the decade prior to the Civil War assume the question pertains to that time period.
The assertion of pap Finn comes down to him saying "Why, they said he couldn’t be sold till he’d been in the State six months, and he hadn’t been there that long yet." (other parts left out as not relevant and containing considerable amounts of abusive language)
As pertaining to comments and some research in other states - https://www.georgiaarchives.org/assets/documents/Slave_Laws_of_Georgia_1755-1860.pdf
it seems not the case that this law was found everywhere - I am now wondering if it was even true in Missouri or other states in that time period.
Both Georgia and, evidently Virginia in that time period, had laws forbidding manumission, and freed slaves from entering the state - from resource above

Free persons of color from another state and seamen are prohibited
from entering the state.

So the question now is - was it true that a freed slave in Missouri from the time of the 1850s onward could be taken after 6 months in the state and put up for auction.
preliminary research suggests that it might have been https://www.nps.gov/articles/000/to-forever-set-free-the-manumission-of-robert-green.htm

Manumissions were more common in Missouri, where there were no laws
outlawing manumissions and no requirements for a freed person to leave
the state (although they were required to purchase a freedom license
that was to be on their person at all times).

because it was more likely that freed slaves might be in Missouri, but also given Missouri's rather supportive view of manumission (in comparison to other states) it would also seem unlikely that they would allow a freed slave with a freedom license and everything to actually be taken for auction after 6 months in the state.

Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)

I think it will be nearly impossible to provide an Authoritative answer to this question. The answer will vary state by state and time by time.  I'd have to go back to my sources to prepare a minimally acceptable answer, but the status/role/risk for free African Americans changed dramatically after slave importation halted.

Slavery was a state institution, not a national institution. Laws would have always varied state to state.

Is there a reason that the question is specific to African American man?

The laws regulating slavery were state laws, so they would have varied by state (which is why you had "free state"s and "slave state"s in the first place). So this can't really be answered for a general case.


is there a reason question specific to African American man?
Book had example of man, thus I followed that


preliminary research - none because I don't even know where to look online for this kind of thing.


The laws regulating slavery were state laws
The Fugitive slave Act of of 1850 was a national law - so there were obviously some national laws around slavery as well as state statutes.


A good starting point may be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_Negro#Regional_differences . However, a useful answer to this question is possible, even if it just outlines the extreme cases: communities of free blacks in some places (maybe Lousiana?) and laws banning free blacks from some other places (Virginia?).

move comments into question.

Providing an exact quote from the book would clarify what exactly we are trying to evaluate here.

I have changed the question and narrowed scope based on various comments and original source material (Adventures of Huckleberry Finn)

and don't forget: slavery wasn't specific to skin colour. Blacks could be free, could own slaves. And whites could be slaves, it just wasn't as common as a percentage of the population.

In Virginia, in this obvious case of Archibald Batte, a free black man could not only remain free but possess his own black slaves.

Link: https://www.jstor.org/stable/4248955
This was far from exceptional - though definitely unusual. As the first page notes:

There had certainly been free black Virginians who owned slaves before Batte, and others would do so after him.


Perhaps not "exceptional", but any implication this was the norm would be very misleading. About a quarter century after independence (1806), Virginia passed a law requiring newly freed blacks to leave the state or be re-enslaved (Mr. Batte was grandfathered in for the last 24 years of his life). After Nat Turner's Rebellion, the legal (and social) oppression escalated. It was only really a brief time after the Nation's founding where a Mr. Batte could happen there.

And keep in mind that Virginia was unusual among the slave states.  Further south, the laws tended to be stricter.

There was also a 60-year period before then (in the early and mid 1700s) where Virginia tried to attack the same problem by outlawing the freeing of any slaves. Mr. Batte managed to dodge both prohibitions through biographical coincidence.

From some investigation I did yesterday it seems likely that earlier laws allowed free black people  to have equal rights to free white people, but looking at say Georgia https://www.georgiaarchives.org/assets/documents/Slave_Laws_of_Georgia_1755-1860.pdf  you can see how the laws over time clamped down on this so that a freed black person in a couple decades before the civil war would have had a pretty bad time of it.

Doesn't really address the question at all, which specifically references slave-holding states on the Mississippi, like Missouri.

I voted it up because after lots of discussion the question was edited to be more precise - should I have instead asked a new question? At any rate this answer was more relevant to the old question than it is to this one - so it seems that probably I am in the wrong to have edited the question in stead of making new?

I guess it depended on a few factors, like possessing possible papers showing that an African-American was free and not a slave. But in some states and territories, there were at least a few black people who owned slaves.

Please add sources to support your answer. Thank you.
